# popup trigger when click the input field in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dom

I am create a jquery mobile website.I want a popup raised when i click a input field.

```
<input type="text" class="popup_trigger" name="type_of_services" placeholder="Type Of Services" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" data-clear-btn="true">

<div data-role="popup" id="popup_service" class="popup_service">
   <label for="check_box"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0">service</label>
</div>
```

jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".popup_trigger").click(function() {
      $("#popup_service").popup();
   });
});
```

I also try

```
$(".popup_service").popup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('.popup_triger').on('click', function () {
  $("#popup_service").popup('open');
});
```

You should use **open** method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.popup_triger', function () {
  $("#popup_service").popup();
});
```

also don't use above event inside $(document).ready();

Comment: Thanks a lot your response friend...i put popup('open') this is work. jes-ble-u